# WooCommerce Total # orders

Tags: query, woocommerce-offtopic

total number (#) of orders, maybe create the function in functions.php and call it in a shortcode anywhere in page. I just don't want to update it.

Comment: Third party plugins and themes are off topic here.

Comment: Please, **do not** post the same question twice. You have been a long time member which should know by now, no duplicates and no support questions for third party plugins and themes. Please reread [ask]. Thank you

Comment: @PieterGoosen you understand people are asking third party plugin questions? Do you understand? Check all related questions songdogtech, you too. HYPOCRITES.

Comment: Yes, that is why they get downvoted and closed. :-)

Comment: If you have any more issues, please raise this in [meta](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Before you do, please read [this](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=woocommerce) first. Thank you :-)

Comment: @songdogtech -1, "Third party plugins and themes are off topic here" contradiction. Look at all the woocommerce questions, spread the word.

Comment: @wordpress_designer: what's your point?

Comment: @songdogtech, you made a contradictory statement, and your -1 wasn't justified based on your reasoning.

Comment: @wordpress_designer: Read the FAQ for the site, follow the rules here, or don't participate.

Comment: @songdogtech http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic 

WordPress Stack Exchange is for WordPress developers and administrators to ask questions about:

    theme and plugin development,
    development and management best practices,
    server configuration for WordPress. Checkmate, sport.

Comment: @wordpress_designer: Please get a life. Somewhere.

Comment: @songdogtech turn in your bucketlist gramps.

Comment: @wordpress_designer: "Gramps?" To me, that's a compliment :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this following query to get the total number of orders.

```
 $order_totals = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_sales_overview_order_totals', $wpdb->get_row( "
    SELECT COUNT(posts.ID) AS total_orders FROM {$wpdb->posts} AS posts

    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->postmeta} AS meta ON posts.ID = meta.post_id
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_relationships} AS rel ON posts.ID=rel.object_ID
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->term_taxonomy} AS tax USING( term_taxonomy_id )
    LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->terms} AS term USING( term_id )

    WHERE   meta.meta_key       = '_order_total'
    AND     posts.post_type     = 'shop_order'
    AND     posts.post_status   = 'publish'
    AND     tax.taxonomy        = 'shop_order_status'
    AND     term.slug           IN ('" . implode( "','", 
apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', 
array( 'completed', 'processing', 'on-hold' ) ) ) . "')
" ) );

$total_orders_count     = absint( $order_totals->total_orders );
```

Comment: @wordpress_designer Please stay away from rude or offensive comments. Stay professional instead. Actually Pieter is right. Properly formatted code is a _must_ on this site as questions do not only serve as quick answer, but as reference for later visitors. Instead of being rude you could have taken the time and just file an [edit] and fix the answer. Joined efforts are what drives a site like this one. Thanks for keeping that in mind for the future.

Comment: I have properly formatted your code to make it more readable. Please keep in mind that the WYSIWYG is there to help you :-)